# Jenkins Linux server with builds on CIFS share

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In our production we are using jenkins server on a centos machine. But we were given a CIFS backup server for builds. we used jenkins configure page option to point to the folder in the CIFS share. But we noticed, the build history is not able to be populated by the web server. We noticed, jenkins on centos is not able to create symlinks to the folders on a cifs share.

Any suggestion to overcome or workaround this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be either of the below :

1. Check for the compatibility of the 32 bit
2. The path which you configured in the Jenkins to the CIFS share (Check it and go for the directory above the path)